# Why is a story not called a “-logue”, though it has a prologue and an epilogue?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, writing

The [Merriam Webster Dictionary defines *-logue*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logue) as:

> indicating speech or discourse of a particular kind.

I understand that *-logue* is a combining form noun, but it has always struck me as odd that a narrative does not have a more formal name to match *epilogue* and *prologue*. Is there a more formal name for a story along the lines of *prologue*?

Comment: A story has a dialogue; the written/spoken exchange between characters.

Comment: Some *logs* tell a story. A story could be a *log*, but its etymology has no relation to *-logue*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[*Prologue*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prologue) and [*epilogue*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=epilogue) use a form of the Greek *λόγος* (*logos*), which means “a speaking”. The word [*lecture*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=lecture) is the word for the speech itself, stemming again from *λόγος*. Though it doesn't use -*logue*, it maintains the same roots.

Note that *lecture* has the alternate meaning of “a reading”, so it makes sense as a story. *Lecture* has [lost](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lecture) this meaning in most cases, but even using the meaning *speech* fits in with *prologue* (before speech) and *epilogue* (after speech). Since *pro-* and *epilogue* refer to a “speech”, *lecture* fits in even with its current usage.

Answer (score 2):

If I just wanted a more formal/technical (to literary discussion) term for “story”, I’d probably go with *narrative*, or simply *work*, if I wanted to avoid bringing up discussion about whether the story is in fact a narrated thing. I would likely avoid *lecture*, since its most salient meaning in modern English is “reading/explaining something out loud to other people” (“my mom lectured me about my grades”, “the teacher lectured about chinese history”).

As for why there’s no word for “story” analogous to *prologue/epilogue*, all I can say is that English happens not to have a word of that sort. There are a myriad of ways that a language can derive a word for a concept, and English happens not to have derived a word from Greek *-logue* to refer to the story itself as opposed to the epilogue and prologue, like it did for *prologue* and *epilogue* themselves. Instead it uses a French borrowing *story*, or a Latinate borrowing *narrative*. You might as well ask why English doesn’t have a French loan for “invention” but instead has a Latinate one.